# Mango plant is dying

Tags: diseases, pest-control, seedlings, discoloration, mango

My mango plant (Mallika variety) recently had what seemed like a mealybug infestation. I applied EndAll pesticide and 70% isopropyl alcohol, and now the bugs mostly seem to be gone.

However, I notice that the leaves are browning and blotching as follows. The soil also seems ridden with bugs (see the white-ish layer at the top, though all soil seems to have lots of tiny insects). I just bought a greenhouse, new grow lights, and am monitoring the temperature of its indoor surroundings.

I am not sure how to treat the mango, nor if it can survive. It used to be a rapid grower this summer and extremely healthy -- I don't know what happened and how to restore it to health. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Browning and curling of leaves]

[image: Overall damage]

[image: Leaf discoloration]

Comment: Maybe you can post a photos of the soil and a bug.